# Correlation matrix not working in new version of Vega?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I was using Elastic 6.6.0 and kibana 6.6.0, vega and vega-lite were not experimental, every thing works good.

Now updated to elastic 7.6.0 and kibana 7.6.0 were vega and vega-lite showing experimental, also in version elastic 7.9.3 and kibana 7.9.3.

First question, whether experimental can be used for production integration, because don't want that to be dropped out or something after integration.

Second,
I created a correlation matrix in kibana 6.6.0

Used following code

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v3.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "Correlation Matrix",
    "anchor": "middle",
    "fontSize": 16,
    "frame": "group",
    "offset": 4
  },
  "data":[
    {
      "name": "feature_correlation",
      "url": {
        "%context%": true, 
        "index": "creditloan.ml_models_v1.creditloandata-xgbclassifier-09dec2020-16h34m03s.corrmatrix",
        "body": {
          "size" : 0,
          "aggs": {
              "statistics": {
                  "matrix_stats": {
                      "fields": ['other_parties', 'purpose', 'housing','credit_amount', 'savings_status', 'employment', 'duration', 'residence_since', 'num_dependents', 'installment_commitment', 'own_telephone', 'credit_history', 'foreign_worker', 'property_magnitude', 'other_payment_plans', 'personal_status', 'checking_status', 'existing_credits', 'asnm', 'job', 'age']
                  }
              }
          }
        }
      },
        "format": {"property": "aggregations.statistics.fields"},
      "transform": [
              {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.other_parties", "as": "other_parties"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.purpose", "as": "purpose"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.housing", "as": "housing"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.credit_amount", "as": "credit_amount"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.savings_status", "as": "savings_status"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.employment", "as": "employment"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.duration", "as": "duration"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.residence_since", "as": "residence_since"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.num_dependents", "as": "num_dependents"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.installment_commitment", "as": "installment_commitment"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.own_telephone", "as": "own_telephone"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.credit_history", "as": "credit_history"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.foreign_worker", "as": "foreign_worker"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.property_magnitude", "as": "property_magnitude"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.other_payment_plans", "as": "other_payment_plans"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.personal_status", "as": "personal_status"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.checking_status", "as": "checking_status"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.existing_credits", "as": "existing_credits"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.asnm", "as": "asnm"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.job", "as": "job"},
                {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.correlation.age", "as": "age"},
              {"type": "fold", "fields": ['other_parties', 'purpose', 'housing','credit_amount', 'savings_status', 'employment', 'duration', 'residence_since', 'num_dependents', 'installment_commitment', 'own_telephone', 'credit_history', 'foreign_worker', 'property_magnitude', 'other_payment_plans', 'personal_status', 'checking_status', 'existing_credits', 'asnm', 'job', 'age']},
              {"type": "project", "fields": ["name", "key", "value"]}
      ]  
    }],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "feature_correlation", "field": "name"},
      "range": "width"
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "feature_correlation", "field": "key"},
      "range": "height"
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": {"scheme": "Viridis"},
      "domain": {"data": "feature_correlation", "field": "value"},
      "zero": false, 
      "nice": true
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
      {
        "orient": "bottom", 
        "scale": "x", 
        "labelOverlap":false,
        "domain": false,
        "title": "Features",
        "encode": {
          "labels": {
            "update": {
              "angle": {"value": -50},
              "fontSize": {"value": 10},
              "align": {"value": "right"}
            }
          }
        }  
      },
      {
        "orient": "left", 
        "scale": "y", 
        "domain": false,
        "title": "Features"
        "encode": {
          "labels": {
            "update": {
              "fontSize": {"value": 10},
              "align": {"value": "right"}
            }
          }
        }
      }
  ],
  "legends": [
    {
      "direction": "vertical",
      "orient": "bottom", 
      "fill": "color",
      "type": "gradient",
      "title": "Correlation",
      "titleFontSize": 12,
      "titlePadding": 4,
      "gradientLength": {"signal": "height - 16"}
      "encode": {
          "labels": {
            "update": {
              "fontSize": {"value": 12}
            }
          }
      }
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "feature_correlation"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "name"},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "key"},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": 1},
          "height": {"scale": "y", "band": 1},
              "tooltip": {"signal": "datum.name + ' - ' + datum.key + ': ' + format(datum.value, '.4f')"}
        },
        "update": {
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "value"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Works Good

[image]

After update to kibana 7.6.0 also tried in Kibana 7.9.3

Same Code shows like below, also changed the version as "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v4.3.0.json", still not working

[image]

May I know how to fix this

Third Question: Online Vega Editors using verions like

vega - v5, but if i use in kibana 7.9.3 or 7.6.0 i get

```
The input spec uses vega v5, but current version of vega is 4.3.0
```

vega-lite - v4, if i use v4, i get

```
The input spec uses vega-lite v4, but current version of vega-lite is 2.6.0.
```

May i know whats that mean and what should i use

Comment: Regarding Third Question, Tried Elastic/Kibana 7.10.1 released 10 Dec 2020, vega and vega-lite is not experimental

Comment: Still Correlation Matrix not showing up in 7.10.1

Comment: First comment, is about regarding First Question not 3rd Question, Tried Elastic/Kibana 7.10.1 released 10 Dec 2020, vega and vega-lite is not experimental

Answer (score 0):

Made this change, single quotes to double quotes, it worked

```
{"type": "fold", "fields": ["installment_commitment", "credit_amount", "num_dependents","duration",  "existing_credits", "asnm", "age", "residence_since", "purpose", "own_telephone", "property_magnitude", "job", "housing", "personal_status", "checking_status", "other_parties", "other_payment_plans", "savings_status", "employment", "foreign_worker","credit_history"]}
```