# How to hide tooltip of overlapped line charts in vega-lite?

Tags: vega-lite

I have multiple line chart with tooltip showing the data, line chart looks like

[image]

I configured to show only the line that is clicked in legend and its tooltip when hover over the dot

[image]
[image]

Since there are many parameter line which overlaps at some points, the tooltip sometimes showing the different parameter that is hiding, for example, in the above picture, I selected PRAUC line from legend and hover on its tooltip, but for the same line if I hover on different point, its showing different parameter value as that line is overlapping on this one, as below, but its line is hidden
[image]

I have set the opacity value to 0.02 for the line, but even though if i hover i can see the tooltips, is it possible to show the tooltip for only the line that is selected, my full code is below

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.6.0.json",
  "title": "Model Dashboard",
  "data": {
    "url" : {
        "%context%": true,
        "index": "creditloan.ml_models_v2.comparison",
        "body": {
          "size":10000,
          "_source": ["Metrics","Value","modelName","modelAlgorithm","modelStartTime"],
        }
      }  
      "format": {"property": "hits.hits"},
  }, 
 "transform": [{
      "filter": "datum._source.Value <= 1.0"
     }],
 "mark": {
    "type": "line",
    "point": {
      "size": 250
    }
    "strokeWidth": 4,
    "strokeCap" : "round",
    "interpolate" :"monotone"
  },
 "selection": {
    "industry": {
      "type": "multi", "fields": ["_source.Metrics"], "bind": "legend"
    }
  },
 "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "_source.modelStartTime", 
          "type": "nominal", 
          "title":"Models"
          "axis": {
            "labelAngle": -20,
            "labelLimit": 500,
            "labelFontSize" : 14
            },
          "sort": {"order": "descending", "field": "_source.modelStartTime"}  
          },
    "y": {"field": "_source.Value", 
          "type": "quantitative", 
          "title":"Metric Score",
          "scale": { "domain": [0.0, 1.0] }  
          },
    "color": {"field": "_source.Metrics", 
              "type": "nominal", 
              "title":"Metrics"},
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "_source.Metrics", "type": "nominal", "title":"Metric"},
      {"field": "_source.Value", "type": "quantitative", "title":"Value"},
      {"field": "_source.modelAlgorithm", "type": "nominal", "title":"ModelAlgorithm"},
      {"field": "_source.modelStartTime", "type": "nominal", "title":"ModelStartTime"},
      {"field": "_source.modelName", "type": "nominal", "title":"ModelName"}
    ],
    "opacity": {
      "condition": {"selection": "industry", "value": 1},
      "value": 0.02
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it so that the tooltip doesn't show for hidden data, you can filter the data based on the selection; i.e. add this to your list of transforms:

```json
{"filter": {"selection": "industry"}}
```

and then remove the opacity encoding.

Comment: thats perfect, Thanks, also could you please help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65226557/correlation-matrix-not-working-in-new-version-of-vega